# Throttling Processes using Clojure core.async

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, clojure

I am trying to use clojure core.async channels to throttle memory-intensive concurrent processes. Each process loads an image into memory and applies a watermark. If I try to process too many images concurrently, I get OOM errors.

The pattern below seems to work, but it feels a bit inelegant. My question is, is there a better way to do this with core.async? Or, should I just use the java concurrency stuff to do this instead (i.e. create a fixed sized thread pool, etc).

The basic concept in the code below is to use a global fixed size channel, `tchan` which is used to throttle what goes into `in-chan`, basically limiting the number of concurrent processes to the size of `tchan`.

In the code below, `process-images` is the entry point.

```
(def tbuff (buffer 20))

(def tchan
  "tchan is used to throttle the number of processes
  tbuff is a fixed size buffer"
  (chan tbuff))

(defn accum-results
  "Accumulates the images in results-chan"
  [n result-chan]
  (let [chans [result-chan (timeout timeout-ms)]]
    (loop [imgs-out  []
           remaining n]
      (if (zero? remaining)
        imgs-out
        (let [[img-result _] (alts!! chans)]
          (if (nil? img-result)
            (do
              (log/warn "Image processing timed out")
              (go (dotimes [_ remaining] (<! tchan)))
              imgs-out)
            (do
              (go (<! tchan))
              (recur (conj imgs-out img-result) (dec remaining)))))))))

(defn process-images
  "Concurrently watermarks a list of images
  Images is a sequence of maps representing image info
  Concurrently fetches each actual image and applies the watermark
  Returns a map of image info map -> image input stream"
  [images]
  (let [num-imgs (count images)
        in-chan  (chan num-imgs)
        out-chan (chan num-imgs)]
    ;; set up the image-map consumer
    ;; asynchronously process things found on in-chan
    (go
      (dotimes [_ num-imgs]
        ; block here on input images
        (let [img-in (<! in-chan)]
          (thread
            (let [img-out (watermark/watermarked-image-is img-in)]
              (>!! out-chan [img-in img-out]))))))
    ;; put images on in-chan
    (go
      (doseq [img images]
        (>! tchan :x)
        (>! in-chan img)))
    ;; accum results
    (let [results (accum-results num-imgs out-chan)]
      (log/info (format "Processed %s of %s images and tbuff is %s"
                        (count results) num-imgs (count tbuff)))
      (into {} results))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is exactly what [pipeline](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/pipeline) is for.

And here's an example:

```
user> (require '[clojure.core.async :refer [<! <!! chan go go-loop pipeline pipeline-blocking pipeline-async] :as async])

user> (let [output (chan)
            input (async/to-chan (range 10))]
        (go-loop [x (<! output)]
          (println x))
        (pipeline 4
                  output
                  (map #(do
                          (Thread/sleep (rand-int 200))
                          (println "starting" %)
                          (Thread/sleep 1000)
                          (println "finished" %)
                          (inc %)))
                  input))
#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x3f434b5a "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@3f434b5a"]
user> starting 0
starting 3
starting 1
starting 2
finished 0
1
finished 3
finished 1
finished 2
starting 4
starting 5
starting 6
finished 4
finished 5
finished 6
```

Comment: In the example I edited in here, it's worth noting that the call to map is a transducer and not a lazy sequence, it just looks like one.